# How do I connect Google Form from Template to Google AppsScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have made a Google Form using a template from forms.google.com. I want to create a script (and I have the logic for it) but I don't know how to get them to work together. What do I do to connect the two? I've tried exporting form HTML but that was to no avail. What is it that I'm supposed to do? Help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Using the script editor of the form?

Comment: @timmer That's what I would have thought but I need the HTML for the form and Google Forms does not provide it unless I'm missing something. You click "script editor" and then it brings me to code.gs but no html is present.

Comment: Why do you need the html?

Comment: @TrentXavier Sorry, I misunderstood you.

Comment: @TheMaster that's what the GoogleAppsScript needs in order to implement custom functions (like uploaded file renaming, etc). Do I not need the HTML?

Comment: [These](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms) are the only things you could do with apps script and those don't need html

Comment: @TrentXavier [Here](https://qiita.com/tetsunosukeito/items/b2e784e813944135785b) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891218/file-upload-item-type-in-google-forms) you can find some information about manipulating uploaded files ("FILE_UPLOAD").

Comment: To link an Apps Script with a Google Form you can open the Form UI and click on the three dots on the top right -> "Script editor", then an Apps Script will open and you can use the [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms) to manipulate the Form. Using Forms Service is the only way to manipulate a Form programatically. Does this answer your question?